# Strange behavior when dragging a QTreeWidgetItem on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a very simple Qt Window containing a QTreeWidget with dragEnabled enabled and some items using Qt 5 Designer, and then exported the code to Python 3 with pyuic5. When running the resulting program on macOS sierra, if I reorder an item by dragging and dropping it, the item below the dropped item disappears instead of just reordering it.

How do I fix this unexpected behaviour on macOS?

[This is the generated python3 code.](https://qbin.io/state-dame-5ej1)

The same code runs fine on Kubuntu and Windows:

- [Here is a sample video of the code running on Kubuntu.](https://streamable.com/9hcch)
- [Here is a sample video of the code running on macOS Sierra, failing.](https://streamable.com/j0c1m)

On Kubuntu and Windows, the QTreeWidgetItem gets reordered to where is dropped as expected, without removing any other items like it happens on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem using Qt from C++. It appears to be caused by [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-74022). It looks like the only solution is to upgrade to Qt 5.13+ (or downgrade to an earlier version before the bug was introduced).